# Mysql keeps restarting/shutting down after macOS update

Tags: mysql, macos

I applied the macOS 10.15.5 update and now MySql wouldn't stay started. The problem specified in the error log was that mysql couldn't "persist" the /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log. This is the exact issue that happened with the macOS 10.15.5 update. Can anyone explain why it is happening?

I was able to add the var/log/mysql folder and changed ownership to mysql:mysql. All of a sudden the slow-query.log file shows up without my re-creating it. Why does that happen?

Would the MacOS update change permissions of the folder such that the folder and any enclosing files were there all along, but became hidden. Why would changing the owner all of a sudden make the folder visible or is that normal behavior? (I am a member of the wheel group).

As soon as I changed the ownership, MySql started and stayed started. I would just like to understand what might have happened to cause this.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Dba or superuser sister sites can offer you more help in admin questions like this.

Comment: Thanks. Reposting on server fault sister site.